# Lodash uniqWith, how say lodash keep last duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

Hello i'm using lodash uniqWith method for remove duplicated items which have same id in my array.

but lodash keep first duplicated item. 
But i wan't to keep last duplicated item.

what can i do for that ?

```
var result = _.uniqWith(editedData, function(arrVal, othVal) {
      return arrVal.id === othVal.id;
    });
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way? Reverse the array first (after cloning it to avoid mutation).

```
var result = _.uniqWith(_.reverse(_.clone(editedData)), function(arrVal, othVal) {...});
```

You can also simplify your code:

```
var result = _.uniqWith(_.reverse(_.clone(editedData)), ({ id: a }, { id: b }) => a === b);
```

Comment: reverse will mutate the original array

Comment: Would `_.reverse(_.clone(editedData))` be better @OriDrori?

Comment: It would mutate the clone, and not the original, so yes. You can also use spread  to get a shallow clone.

Comment: You saved my day thank you :) nice approach with reverse it’s worked

Comment: No problem @user3348410, always glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a uniqByLast function using `_.flow()`. Use `_.keyBy()` to get an object by `id`, and `_.values()` to get an an array:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, keyBy, values } = _

const lastUniqBy = iteratee => flow(
  pr(keyBy, iteratee),
  values
)

const arr = [{ id: 1, val: 1 }, { id: 1, val: 2 }, { id: 2, val: 1 }, { id: 2, val: 2 }]

const result = lastUniqBy('id')(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same idea using lodash/fp:

```js
const { flow, keyBy, values } = _

const lastUniqBy = iteratee => flow(
  keyBy(iteratee),
  values
)

const arr = [{ id: 1, val: 1 }, { id: 1, val: 2 }, { id: 2, val: 1 }, { id: 2, val: 2 }]

const result = lastUniqBy('id')(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```